# Send data returned from javascript function to Flask backend

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have a simple javascript function that executes when a button is clicked and I want to send some data from that function to the Flask backend.

My initial idea was this:

```
function sendDataToBacked() {
    data = "I want to send this to backend"
    document.getElementById("myButton").value = data;
}
```

I set the button value to 'data' and then with a form I send that value to the backend like this.

```
<form id="myForm" method="POST"></form>
<button form="myForm" id="myButton" name="button" onclick="sendDataToBacked()">Send</button>
```

And finally the python backend would look like this:

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.form['button'])

    return render_template("index.html")
```

But it doesnt work :(
Any idea how I can achieve this with pure javascript? (I know you can do it with AJAX)

Comment: if you want to send data without reloading web page then you have to learn AJAX - there is no other option.

Comment: button has to be inside `<form></form>` but you have it outside `<form></form>` and form will not send it and you can't get it in Flask -  `<form> <button></button> </form>`. I'm not sure but button may need also `type="submit"` - without this it may not know if it should submit or reset data in form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written an example with two buttons, the first one makes the submit itself and send the data to the backend, the second one calls a function and it makes the submit.
I have used `list(request.form.keys())[0]` to identify which button is making the submit.

Backend:

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if list(request.form.keys())[0] == 'button':
            print(request.form['button'])

        if list(request.form.keys())[0] == 'button2':
            print(request.form['button2'])

    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Frontend:

```
<form action="" method="post" id='myForm'>
    <button name="button" value="value">Send</button>
</form>

<form action="" method="post" id='myForm2'>
    <button id="myButton2" name="button2" value=0 onclick="modifyData()">Send</button>
</form>

<script>
    function modifyData() {
        data = "I want to send this to backend"
        document.getElementById("myButton2").value = data;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<button>` has to be inside `<form></form>` to send it.

```
<form method="POST">
<button id="myButton" name="button" onclick="sendDataToBacked()">Send</button>
</form>
```

If you want to send other values then you have to also put them inside `<form></form>`

---

You may have many forms on the same page and every form need own button to send it - so form have to know which button belong to form.

---

Minimal working example

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    print(request.form)
    return render_template_string('''
<script>
function sendDataToBacked() {
    data = "I want to send this to backend";
    document.getElementById("myButton").value = data;
}
</script>
<form method="POST">
<button id="myButton" name="button" onclick="sendDataToBacked()">Send</button>
</form>
''')

app.run()
```

but this code will also reload page. If you want to send it without reloading then you will have to learn AJAX.

---

**EDIT:** the same with `AJAX` using modern method `fetch` instead of older `XMLHttpRequest` or external library `jQuery`

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    print(request.form)
    return render_template_string('''
<script>
function sendDataToBackendAjax(event) {

    // create own form in memory
    const formData = new FormData();

    // set values in this form
    formData.append("button", "I want to send this to backend");

    fetch("/ajax", {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData
        //headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        //body: JSON.stringify(formData)
    })
    .then(function(response){
        data = response.json();  // get result from server as JSON
        //alert(data);
        return data; 
    })
    .then(function(data){ 
        alert(data.info);
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });
    
    event.preventDefault(); // don't send in normal way and don't reload page
}
</script>

<form method="POST" action="/ajax">
<button id="myButton" name="button" onclick="sendDataToBackendAjax(event)">Send Ajax</button>
</form>
''')

@app.route('/ajax', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def ajax():
    print(request.form)
    return jsonify({'result': 'OK', 'info': 'Hello World!'})  # send result to browser as JSON

app.run()  #debug=True
```

Comment: Although I marked @fullfine answer as the accepted this one helped me a lot too (specially the AJAX example, as I am considering using it). Thank you.